# How to use Backbonejs for large scalable applications?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Based on my research I believe the situation can get cumbersome if BackboneJS alone is used for building a large scale client centric application. Is there a best approach for using BackboneJS to build such applications. I came across a framework called ChaplinJS which is a wrapper around BackboneJS to build large applications. What other frameworks are available like ChaplinJS to use BackboneJS for large projects?

Comment: Have a look at Marionette.
https://github.com/derickbailey/backbone.marionette

Answer (score 1):

Marionette:
https://github.com/derickbailey/backbone.marionette

Answer (score 1):

There are more missing vertebrae in Backbone.js than any one thing is likely to fill. You need to make sure you know what solution you're going to use for validation, binding model variables to form fields and to HTML display (assuming you want two-way binding), templating, modularization/AMD (for example, something like RequireJS), and then maybe on top of that something like Marionette.

I've got a lot more notes than these but I've removed most of them for these topics because they're a little too stream-of-consciousness to be understood easily.

```
Binding
    <https://github.com/theironcook/Backbone.ModelBinder>

Validation
    <https://github.com/toddself/Backbone.Validator>
        Just the validation part of things
    <https://github.com/thedersen/backbone.validation>
        Seems to combine binding and validation
    <https://github.com/n-time/backbone.validations>
        Seems to combine binding and validation

Modules
    <https://github.com/scottburch/river-js>

Templates
    handlebarsjs.com <http://handlebarsjs.com/>
```

Overall, just having finished a large project with it, it wouldn't be my first choice again. It's missing too many pieces that you have to fill in. We would probably see if Ember.js could work better for us.

Comment: Valid points, but one of backbone's strengths is its flexibility to let developers pick the solutions to problems that aren't part of Backbone's core purpose.

Answer (score 0):

[Backbone Aura](http://addyosmani.github.com/backbone-aura/) looks really promising. It's from [Addy Osmani](http://addyosmani.com/blog/) and is based on his ["Patterns for Large Scale JavaScript Applications"](http://addyosmani.com/largescalejavascript/) and [Nicholas Zakas'](http://www.nczonline.net/) ["Scalable Application Architecture"](http://www.slideshare.net/nzakas/scalable-javascript-application-architecture).

The developer preview was released just a few weeks ago, so documentation and tutorials are still scarce. But I like that it has such an impressive pedigree, and how it marries two of the most authoritative approaches to JS architecture (Osmani's Aura had been around for a while in non-Backbone form and several frameworks have been built around the Zakas model as well).

Comment: Addy's book http://addyosmani.github.com/backbone-fundamentals/ is also a great read.

Comment: Aura is still a Developers only framework. I wonder how Aura is compared to ChaplinJS.